# Bootstrap 4 sidebar right position inside div

Tags: bootstrap-4, sidebar

i am using  Bootstrap 4 sidebar inside a div on right position  ,
when I Toggle it (Hide the sidebar) there a horizontal scroll bar appear .
I need to Toggle it (Hide the sidebar) with out the horizontal scroll bar .
sample you can find in :

```
[https://codepen.io/rifaat_ch/pen/jOqxbXp][1]
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `overflow: hidden` to the class `.wrapper` to hide the horizontal scroll bar,

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Forked Codepen:**

> **https://codepen.io/Maniraj_Murugan/pen/vYGjLBm**

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

this

```
$('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
```

by this

```
$('#sidebar').toggle('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
}, 'slow');
```